# Sending a JSON object to a C# WebAPI POST method which takes in a generic abstract class as a parameter

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've got a generic abstract class which describes the type of object that someone would POST into this endpoint, the class is like below along with an example of the type that this class could be:

```
public abstract class Animal<T>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual T Properties{ get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Pig : Animal<List<int>>
    {
        public Pig()
        {
            Name = "pigEntity";
            Properties = new List<int>();
        }
    }
```

The below is what my controller method looks like for calling the API endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("...")]
public async Task<bool> SaveAnimalSetting([FromBody] Animal<JObject> animalType)
{}
```

When trying to call this endpoint through Postman, I am getting back that the input is not valid, the below is the JSON object that I am trying to POST to it, it should be the equivalent of that Pig object above:

```
{
   "key":"pigEntity",
   "value":[
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6
   ]
}
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong, or how an example of a JSON object would look like when calling the endpoint with that generic abstract class as a parameter or if there is any other way of doing it? I found a thread on here where someone also had a generic class and that is the method they were recommended so trying to do the same.

Comment: You are basically asking the deserializer to create instance of an abstract class, which is impossible. Unless you have somewhere code that tells the framework how to deserialize the input into correct derived classes, this cannot work at all. Specifically if you want to go with this approach, you will have to hook into deserialization framework.

Comment: You cannot do this easily.  You will need to specify the actual type expected in the endpoint. Like [FromBody Animal<Dog> anymalType].... further more you should not use an abstract class or an interface.

Comment: You might get away with a custom converter and using a wrapper and explicit types and return object from the properties.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Yes, he would need to write custom converter for (I assume) System.Json JSON serializer

Comment: Is there no way to have it work with the base class (Animal in this case) in the endpoint? As thats the main thing im after. My plan afterwards was to then have a switch case straight off to convert this object into its correct derived class based on what that "key" property is in the JSON. Not implemented this at the moment as couldn't get this to work first so been using a regular JObject parameter for the time being

Comment: You can achieve this by writing  a custom model binder (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0).  I did this a long time ago for MVC4 and wrote a post about it here: https://mrczetty.houseofczetty.com/2013/10/31/abstract-classes-controller-params/  Not sure how relevant it is now, though.

Answer (score 0):

if you trying to use as input parameter

```
{
   "key":"pigEntity",
   "value":[
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6
   ]
}
```

you can use  JObject but only this way

```
public bool SaveAnimalSetting([FromBody] JObject animalType)
{
    var key = animalType["key"].ToString();

    switch (key)
    {
    case "pigEntity":

     var properties = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>> (animalType["value"].ToString());
     var pig = new Pig { Properties = properties };
                    break;
        
                default:
                    break;
            }
}
```

I am sorry but it doesn't make any sense for me. Since each class shoud have special properties, in any case you should know what type needs to be created before  sending json with input parameters. It is only can be usefull if you want to create several different classes in one request.

The problem is that since your neeed to deserialize data, you need to know the type to use to deserialize. Maybe you can create type using reflections, but it takes hundrends more time and resources then using new. I can recommend to use reflections only if there is no way to do task without them.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense. My issue is that there could be different types of Animals, so e.g. Dog or Tiger class, but the way I'm designing it is that each of them will have 2 fields, string Name and Properties, the Name will always be a string but the Properties could be any data type which is why I'm opting to use generics for it

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't make any sense  for me. If   you have to send a special properties for each class, you should know what type before you send input parameters.

Comment: Makes sense with your JObject example. That is what I am using currently for it and its working but was just wondering if theres any way to do it differently rather than using JObject